# How do I detect if no selected item on ComboBox is chosen?

Tags: c#, windows, combobox

In my ComboBox, the field is blank before users click it and choose any item. So without users click on the ComboBox, it remains empty. How do we check whether the ComboBox is empty or not?

This codes gives me an error because there is no item selected yet:

```
if( ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("") )
{
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
if( ComboBox.SelectedItem == null ) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ComboBox.SelectedItems.Count
```

this should work :P it counts selected items. if that number is 0, no items are selected.

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work when `SelectionMode` is `Single`. It'll probably work, but documentation doesn't state that. From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selecteditems.aspx): _When SelectionMode is Multiple or Extended, use the SelectedItems property to get the items that are selected. When SelectionMode is Single, use the Selector.SelectedItem property to get the item that's selected_.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1 )
```